# How to get data from dashboard to table view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

[image: flow example]

---

I would like to pass data from a server to my table view. In the example above, there are three screens. I pass information I get from the QR code to my last screen. I send information from the two input fields to a server. How can I pass the data from my server to a table view?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. First you will have to make the request to your server. You can either use a 3rd party library like [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), or a built in framework.

Then you need to pass that data into your other view controller.

Let's say your second view controller class is defined like so.

```
class SecondViewController: UITableViewController {
    var myData: [String] = [String]()

    //...
```

Then you can display the view controller using the following code.

```
//Display view controller
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
let secondViewController: SecondViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
secondViewController.myData = myData

self.present(secondViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Notice the `secondViewController.myData = myData` which is passing `myData` into that second view controller so that you can use it within that scope.

Then in your `viewDidLoad` of your table view controller you can read the data from `myData` and display it accordingly.

You might need to change the type of `myData` in your `SecondViewController` depending on the type of data you are getting from your server.

Comment: Don't store data in UserDefaults, it's not meant for this. And most importantly don't store anything in UserDefaults if the goal is to pass data between views, this would be a nonsense. Use RAM for this, not storage...

Comment: @Moritz You are right. I was thinking about past projects where we did want to store the data later for various reasons. I will edit to be more clear when I get back to my computer.

Comment: Good. Let's avoid giving bad ideas to beginners. ;)

Comment: @Moritz Just for reference before I edit any tips on what to use besides UserDefaults if the user wanted to store the data for that view for long term purposes? Core Data maybe?

Comment: I don't see in this question any need to store data anywhere. They only need to download, keep in memory, and pass between viewcontrollers.

Comment: @Moritz Just edited, let me know your thoughts and if you have any other suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Looks ok to me. :)